# Rails Routes and Shallow Nested Forms on Many to Many Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I apologize in advance for my long post. I am still new to Rails and have followed many tutorials. I have figured out the standard CRUD basics, but now I wish to try my hand at something more complicated.

I am working with Many to Many associates using has_many :through and belongs_to.

https://github.com/senorlocksmith/nested_forms

I had posted several questions here regarding some forms but figured I might just explain what I am doing and then post a link to a repo so you can see what I have done and maybe give suggestions. For simplicity this is a bare stock Rails 6 repo with no frontside styles or JS to make it messy.

I am trying to create a app that has nested pieces. So I will try to explain it as simply as I can, forgive me if I make this confusing. The capitalized items Project, Script Location and Location are all my Models Views and Controllers. I have created a script_locations_location Model for the join table.

I create a Project in my CRUD. Then that project has many Script Locations. The Script Location is totally dependent on the Project so if I delete the project they are deleted too. I understand the dependent: :destroy part of the model. Then I want to create Location that is associated with the Script Location and this is where it gets tricky. I want all Locations that are added to remain in the database so they might be attached to other Script Locations in the future. I'm not super worried about that right now, but where I am at is confused with handling shallow routes and the join table. Logically I want to create a Project, create many Script Locations, and then add many new Locations under each Script Location respectively but with that kind of navigation. Later I would love to be able to have it setup to attach a pre-existing Location under Script Locations (like add new or attach existing) and also be able to view and filter all Locations independent of the other models.

I have managed to get the guts somewhat working, create the models, database, controllers, and views to some degree. I just don't know how to get it connected for links and correct routing with what's in my head. Once its done I would love to create an example app repo for people who are trying to do the same thing. I have looked and looked but there are very limited full tutorials and examples available.

So my question here is that I have setup my models according to sites and my routes for shallow, but I cannot figure out the controller methods that I will update my views to work with. How does one model the controller for shallow routing and nested models with has_many :through?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: This is far to broad a question. Perhaps this link might help a little at least to get you to a point where you can ask a coding specific question http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?autoplay=true

Comment: I've edited adding my question. I have followed tutorials for nested forms. However when using nested plus shallow routing I cannot pass ids correctly. I think my controller is missing something and I cannot find any tutorial or guide that shares the controller or views when doing something like this.